# how the port number is decided in asp.net debug mode

Tags: asp.net

I have some problem with my pc.When I tried to debug the website using visual studio in my pc..the browser keeps on loading and shows no result.That website runs show in my laptop...
I could not find the problem.Is there any thing to do with localhost port no or there is another reason

Comment: there can one million twenty five thousand and forty five reasons why your website is not loading.. you need to be more clear

Comment: Are you using IIS virtual directory? If yes, you must open the configuration from the web project and set a new one for the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you specify the port you want to use for the ASP.NET Development Server.

1. In Solution Explorer, click the name of the application.
2. In the Properties pane, click the down-arrow beside Use dynamic
   ports and select False from the dropdown list.

   This will enable editing of the Port number property.
3. In the Properties pane, click the text box beside Port number and
       type in a port number.
4. Click outside of the Properties pane. This saves the property
   settings.

   Each time you run a file-system Web site within Visual Web Developer, the ASP.NET Development Server will listen on the specified port.

Details here -: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To see/edit the port your project is run on, go to the project properties (Right-click -> Properties). Go to the Web tab.

Answer (score 1):

The port number is randomly selected, unless you specify a specific port number in the project properties.

Here is the MSDN documentation for [How to: Specify a Port for the ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).